# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory", when using React Native with Hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-hermes

Whenever there is an error in my code while running expo with Hermes locally, I get this error message as well:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kudo\01_Work\Repos\expo\expo\android\versioned-react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine\.cxx\MinSizeRel\6d3b5k69\x86\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'`

Now if I fix the code error, for instance a missing bracket, the aforementioned error also disappears and everything works. However, this error appears no matter what error is in my code, and it's quite lengthy and is preventing me from debugging. If I remove Hermes, the error also disappears, but I would like to use Hermes.

Here is my env info:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD  
      npm: 9.1.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD    
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^46.0.0 => 46.0.15
      react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
      react-dom: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
      react-native: 0.69.6 => 0.69.6
      react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.9
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Things I've tried:

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- Deleting the metro_cache folder in appdata
- `npx expo start --clear`

I expected the error to no longer appear, however the aforementioned steps did nothing at all.

Comment: Did you fixed it ? I'm getting same error :(